# Color Theme Repo Similar to Kuler

Tags: color, adobe-kuler

I have a website where users can create custom designed paper goods. I default the color selections for a template to something popular I found on Kuler, but I've noticed the colors themes that the users come up with are abysmal. It would be great if I could incorporate the Kuler RSS feed right into my site and let user choose from popular themes, but they have a no commercial policy

I'm looking for a set of color themes similar to Kuler that I can incorporate into my web application.

Or, I'm open to any suggestions for helping my users customize their designs by choosing themes that actually look good.

Comment: +1 for recognizing that because Kuler has no commercial policy you can't use it on your site.

Comment: I was looking for these and couldn't find them through google immediately. That's when I remembered this beta site. Made an account just to up vote. Hope to see this thrive!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [ColourLovers](http://www.colourlovers.com/), which is essentially what Kulor is, just with more features, and being older.

While they don't have an adobe plugin, you can download color schemes in adobe pallet formats.

And in specific answer to your want for an RSS like thing, they've got a well documented [api](http://www.colourlovers.com/api), which you can use for free so long as you attribute them and don't use there name to endorse any product that they don't endorse themselves.

I've never used their api myself, however I've seen a cool app for Twitter that will let you use their easy color picker/scheme picker and patterns for a twitter theme.

Comment: Note that all themes on ColourLovers are CC-BY-NC-SA licensed, so you can't use them commercially either.

Answer (score 0):

I've seen many requests for a color picker similar to Adobe's.
I created one that is similar, but probably easier to use as a tool on an actual site.

https://github.com/JSdc/adobe-kuler-clone